# Get cursor state in Excel VBA 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to do a series of mouse clicks and mouse moves (keystroke macro) to enter repetitive data into Oracle (Program/database).

I used Dataload Classic or Dataloader Classic (keystroke program) to enter data into Oracle before but it lacked the "Smarts", so I created my own keystroke program with some "Smarts".

I am using the SLEEP command/function to wait a couple of seconds/milliseconds after every mouse move and mouse click. Sometimes Oracle would be slow and "pause"/"load"/or "freeze up" and the freezing time might exceed the SLEEP command initial wait time and continue on with the program, thus messing everything up.

example:

if something_happens then

sleep 2000

end if

In DataLoad classic/Dataloader Classic there are options to change how long you can wait/pause for every mouse click or mouse move, etc. There is an "HOURGLASS CHECK". This says you may set a time for the program to wait if the mouse is in the hourglass state and the user may enter millisecond or seconds.

Is there Excel VBA code to check the HOURGLASS state of the mouse?

Comment: [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262728(v=vs.60).aspx)? [Another DoEvents Link ... Maybe Better](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/118468)

Comment: What do you mean by the curor state? Where it is in the sheet?  If the loading wheel is going, then there's probably a better way to detect something's going on rather than just what the cursor animation is showing.

Comment: I am writing it in the module, I've been searching online but I am not finding anything. Maybe I'm not searching for the right terms @BruceWayne

Comment: Our main question here is why are you checking the cursor for some action? This sounds like it could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I think your "real" question here is how to determine when a loop is complete (when the mouse would stop being the hourglass)?

Comment: So I am currently making a program in excel vba that automatically enters info into another program. It does the same mouse movements/mouse clicks sequence everytime. The other program which I am interacting with is a bit slow sometimes and it would take time for it to save data when you hit the save button, etc. Right now i am using the sleep function to pause between clicks and movements, but if the program is taking longer to save or what not, the sleep function doesn't know and just keeps going. so i was thinking of reading the cursor state (loading wheel).

Comment: I have edited the description, please read

Comment: There is an "Application.Cursor" property.  Have you tried that?  As a test, something like:  If Application.Cursor = xlWait Then MsgBox "foo"  You could probably wrap a check in a "Do While" loop.  Here is the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198335.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If @sous2817 's suggestion doesn't pan out (and it might not if an application other than Excel is controlling the cursor) -- you'll probably have to do something with the Windows API.

Comment: @sous2817 that is not what I am looking for, that is only applicable on excel. This can be tested, if you have a button and have the code Sleep 5000, click the button and you will see the wheel turn into the hourglass but once you move the mouse over to the desktop or other application, it becomes and arrow.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, I guess I will have to do something with windows API but I do not know how, thus me posting this question asking for help. I'm not a pro at VBA yet sadly :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following function which uses *win api* functions [LoadCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391(v=vs.85).aspx)  and [GetCursorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms648389(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine if the current cursor equals to wait cursor.

The function first loads the win-predefined wait cursor then gets current cursor and checks if they are the same. HTH

```
Option Explicit

Private Const IDC_WAIT As Long = 32514

Private Type POINT
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type CURSORINFO
    cbSize As Long
    flags As Long
    hCursor As Long
    ptScreenPos As POINT
End Type

Private Declare Function GetCursorInfo _
    Lib "user32" (ByRef pci As CURSORINFO) As Boolean
Private Declare Function LoadCursor _
    Lib "user32" Alias "LoadCursorA" _
    (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal lpCursorName As Long) As Long

Public Function IsWaitCursor() As Boolean

    ' Get handle to wait cursor
    Dim handleWaitCursor As Long
    handleWaitCursor = LoadCursor(ByVal 0&, IDC_WAIT)

    Dim pci As CURSORINFO
    pci.cbSize = Len(pci)

    ' Retrieve information about the current cursor
    Dim ret As Boolean
    ret = GetCursorInfo(pci)

    If ret = False Then
        MsgBox "GetCursorInfo failed", vbCritical
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Returns true when current cursor equals to wait cursor
    IsWaitCursor = (pci.hCursor = handleWaitCursor)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking **screen.MousePointer** property if  Busy (Hourglass)

```
While screen.MousePointer = 11
      Sleep(500)
Wend
```