# how to apply vba code of hourglass check (cursor state)

Tags: click, cursor, mouse, wait, hourglass

For this answer, i still can't apply this code on my situation.
[Get cursor state in Excel VBA 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799287/get-cursor-state-in-excel-vba-2013#new-answer?newreg=d34890be1b08423aa39d411628a00fbc)

This is my situation. When vba code running 1st click "retrieve button" in another program/application, after that hourglass condition appears in inconsistent time (depends on internet connection), i want delay running by "do while check during hourglass status" and then go to 2nd click after hourglass disappears.

This is my code :
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
'1st Click
lngStatus = GetCursorPos(typWhere)
SetCursorPos 607, 246 'x and y position
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
'1st Click end

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
'2nd Click
lngStatus = GetCursorPos(typWhere)
SetCursorPos 1100, 475'x and y position
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
'2nd Click end

Then where is i should put the "IsWaitCursor" code between two click ???